# Can I have a different generic type Method in a generic type class

Tags: c#, generic-type-argument

I want something like this

```
public class GenericClass<T1> where T1 : class, new()
{
    public void GenericMethod<T2>(GenericClass<T2> t)
    {
        //do my stuff...
    }
}
```

I got a compile error like so

**The type 'T2' must be a reference type in order to use it as parameter 'T1' in the generic type or method 'Rextester.GenericClass'**

**'T2' must be a non-abstract type with a public parameterless constructor in order to use it as parameter 'T1' in the generic type or method 'GenericClass'**

Type T1 and T2 has no type relationship.
Is it possible?

Comment: Then what's wrong with my syntax? why do I get error?

Comment: Nothing is wrong with your syntax. [You don't get an error from this code](https://rextester.com/NZKJN38739).

Comment: OP, is your code perhaps too trivial to actually demonstrate your issue?

Comment: @Tony, could you please show us the actual code you are using?

Comment: Sorry guys, I figured it out. I posted my error and resolution.

Comment: You should edit your question to include the constraint on `GenericClass`, and then move your fixed version to an answer so that we can vote on it. :-)

Comment: Ok. Will do so good for other people

Answer (score 1):

**Sorry guys my fault**

```
public class GenericClass<T1> where T1: class, new()
{
    // <-- I got an error here because I should add same constraint for T2 as it will be used in GenericClass
    public void GenericMethod<T2>(GenericClass<T2> t) 
    // The following line will work fine
    public void GenericMethod<T2>(GenericClass<T2> t) where T2: class, new()
    {
        //do my stuff...
    }
}
```